# NFS does not work. mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

This is what I got on server:

```
manuel@server ~ $ cat /etc/exports
  /var/share    192.168.178.20(rw, sync)
manuel@server ~ $ cat /etc/hosts.allow 
  portmap: 192.168.178.20
manuel@server /etc $ cat /proc/filesystems | grep nfs
  nodev nfs
  nodev nfs4
```

This is what I get on my machine:

```
manuel@Timeline:~$ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.178.2:/var/share /media/share/
   mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 192.168.178.2:/exports/var/share,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       Manchmal liefert das Syslog wertvolle Informationen – versuchen
       Sie  dmesg | tail  oder so
```

server is Raspbian (Debian Wheezy)
Timeline is Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: `/etc/export` or `/etc/exports`?

Comment: `man exports`.  Normally filename should be `/etc/exports`.

Comment: Have you changed filename on to `/etc/exports`?

Comment: I just corrected it to /etc/exports. No improvement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run `exportfs -a` on the `server` machine.

Also both machines have all of the needed NFS support packages and have nfs support?  You can find if the kernel supports a specific filesystem by examining the output of `cat /proc/filesystems`.

And yes, the filename of the export file needs to be `/etc/exports`

Finally, check to see if you have enabled the NFS daemons during startup.

Comment: Hurray I had syntax errors in `/etc/exports` +1 for `exportfs -a`. But `showmount` still shows no shares. I updated the question. "Finally, check to see if you have enabled the NFS daemons during startup." - How?

Answer (score 34):

The client needs `nfs-common`:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

Refer: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/missing-codepage-helper-program-other-error/

Answer (score 11):

Make sure mount.cifs, mount.nfs is listed into /sbin:

```
ls -l /sbin/mount.cifs
ls -l /sbin/mount.nfs
```

Check to see if package nfs-common, cifs-utils is installed:

```
dpkg -l cifs-utils
dpkg -l nfs-common
```

if `/sbin/mount.nfs` is not already there:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

if `/sbin/mount.cifs` is not already there:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

```
busybox mount -t nfs -o nolock,nfsvers=3,vers=3 192.168.178.2:/var/share /media/share/
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! Could you [edit] your post to explain how this is supposed to solve the problem described in the question, especially in light of the accepted answer?