# mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fdisk

I added a new hard drive (`/dev/sdb`) to Ubuntu Server 16, ran `parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt` and `sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 0G 1074GB`. All went fine. Then I tried to mount the drive

```
mkdir /mnt/storage2
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/storage2
```

It resulted in

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I tried `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/storage2` with identical outcome. I've done this stuff many times before and have never ran into anything like this. I've already read this [mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb on CentOS 6.0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22653/mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-on-dev-sdb-on-centos-6-0) to no avail.

fdisk output regarding the drive

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000 GiB, 1073741824000 bytes, 2097152000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 0E136427-03AF-48E2-B56B-A467E991629F

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 2097149951 2097147904 1000G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Hint for anyone else coming across this: run dmesg, it may give you more information on what your problem actually is.

Comment: To add to the suggestion by @WinstonEwert, run `dmesg` without piping it to `grep`.  The messages I needed to see had no mention of my device, label, or mount point (other than `dm-0` which I was not looking for)!

Comment: dmesg told me I had "default" in /etc/fstab, "unrecognized option", when it should have been "defaults".

Comment: If you came to this question through a search, but ***your*** problem involves NFS, see [NFS does not work. mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65376/80216).

Comment: I added a new drive to the server and I accidently swapped the SATA cables from some drives. That was the problem for me. Switched them back to the way they were and it was all fixed.

Comment: **FYI** For LVM, a similar symptom can arise, even though the filesystem is ok. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/697043/190880). This should **never** be overlooked.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

**WARNING: This will wipe out your drive!**

---

You still need to create a (*new*) file system (aka "format the partition").

**Double-check** that you really want **to overwrite** the current content of **the specified partition**! Replace *`XY`* accordingly, but double check that you are specifying the correct partition, e.g., `sda2`, `sdb1`:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdXY
```

`parted` / `mkpart` does not create a file system. 
The [Parted User's Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/mkpart.html) shows:

> #### 2.4.5 mkpart
>
> **Command: `mkpart [part-type fs-type name] start end`**
>
> Creates a new partition,
> ***without* creating a new file system** on that partition.

<sup>[Emphasis added.]</sup>

Comment: This will wipe out your current drive !!

Comment: In doing this, I get a permission denied error. Have you encountered this before?

Comment: @Kosta you must run the command as a superuser (i.e. `sudo`)

Comment: @SudarP it wipes out the /dev/sdb1 device. Not your current. Just execute if you are sure of what you are doing (https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4)

Comment: You could also be trying to mount say `sda` instead of `sda2` (or whichever number your ext4 partition is on). As was my case today... I'm half asleep

Comment: I get "Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdc Proceed anyway?"

Comment: @SudarP I does not wipe out your drive. It creates a new filesystem on the specified partition. To "wipe out" a partition or a whole drive one should use `wipefs` or `dd`. The question indicates that there was no filesystem before, so it's very unlikely that something important could get lost.

Comment: @tremendows, rudimeier: I agree that the command is appropriate for the OP, but also agree with SudarP that a command like this that can mess up an existing filesystem should come with a prominent warning. Other people reading question may have intended /dev/sdc1 or somesuch and could seriously regret executing this command.

Comment: It's important to mention that the "device" that gets wiped is only the partition that is selected, not the entire drive. So `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4` will keep `sda1`-`sda3` intact. So, as clarified, it will not wipe your current drive, unless you attempt to wipe it by missing to provide the device number in the command, in which case [a prompt will ask for confirmation](https://serverfault.com/questions/413496/how-do-i-script-mkfs-asking-is-entire-device-not-just-one-partition-proceed-a).

Comment: I just `sudo apt install ntfs-3g` and drivers come back to work

Comment: I solved bad superblock with recreating (recovering actually - original and uncorrupted) partition table with `testdisk` as recommended one of the other answers. My answer to related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747574/459266.

Comment: my external HDD is now empty after the command run.. how to recover it again?

Answer (score 50):

I had this problem with /dev/sda on Ubuntu 16.04 I solved it by booting into a live usb and doing the following:

To see your disks use `lsblk`

If you can see your drive thats good, run `fdisk -l` to see if the system can use it.

Run this command to attempt to repair bad superblocks on the drive.

`fsck /dev/sda1` (replace /dev/sda1 with the drive you want to fix).

When it asks to repair blocks select yes by pressing '**y**'

**Allow fsck to repair all bad blocks.**

Then I was able to mount the device using

```
sudo mount /dev/sda /media/ubuntu
```

This solved it for me.

Comment: Trying this, I get a permission denied error for both fdisk -l and the fsck command. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @NoVa This may be out of date, but in generaly permission denied means you must precede the command with sudo such that you have root permisions.

Comment: You are assuming the file system is ext.

Comment: No, clean, 1801983/9043968 files, 33913312/36160000 blocks. This only for certain condition.

Comment: If you have a corrupted ubuntu installation and you are trying to recover it by booting from an external device, this is the answer.
I was about to dump my ubuntu HD and this saved me. 
Thank you!

Comment: great job! thanks a lot.

Comment: I used `xfs_repair` on my xfs raid10 array and then was able to mount it. When I tried `fsck` it told me to use `xfs_repair`.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only thing I could find that helped me!

Comment: Allow me to contribute my two cents by mentioning that, if your LV's underlying filesystem is JFS, you will get this message if the FS is in a dirty state, e.g. its machine was forcibly powered off. This is because the JFS driver refuses to mount dirty volumes, and at the same time its error message is not exactly informative. In this case, you must run `fsck -y (your LV)` before mounting it. I just spent a good couple minutes doing that before remembering that my computer had indeed suffered a power outage a couple days before, so I fsck'd my JFS filesystem and everything was fine afterwards.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the solution was install `nfs-utils` on the client side.

**CentOS/Red Hat:**

```
yum install nfs-utils
```

**Ubuntu/Debian:**

```
apt update
apt install nfs-kernel-server
```

Comment: For Arch: `sudo pacman -S nfs-utils`

Answer (score 11):

I have a different process for this that replaced the bad superblock with one of the alternatives.  FSCK can be a "lossy" process because FSCK may want to remove too much data or to remove data from a sensitive location (e.g. data directory for a data base) so there are times when I don't want to use it or it doesn't work.

You can sudo yourself silly or just become root for the process.  Just remember that when you are root, Linux assumes that you know what you're doing when you issue commands.  If so directed, it will speedily delivery Mr. Bullet to Mr. Foot. Like many other things, with great power comes great responsibility.  That concludes my warning on running your system as root.

```
sudo -s

fdisk -l
```

Figure out which device - assuming /dev/sdc1 for this example along with EXT4 as its the most common for this explanation.

```
fsck -N /dev/sdc1
```

Your device and your file system (ZFS, UFS, XFS, etc.) may vary so know what you have first.  Do not assume it's EXT4. Ignoring this step can cause you problems later if it's NOT an EXT4 file system.

```
fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdc1
```

Get your error message which says the superblock is bad.  You don't want to do this if your superblock is OK.

```
mke2fs -n /dev/sdc1
```

This will output the alternate superblocks stored on your partition.

```
*Superblock backups stored on blocks:
32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208*
```

Pick an alternate superblock - keep in mind that the first one is the default and its bad so let's not use that one.  **You will also want to pick one from the list you get from your partition. Do not use the example. Your superblocks may be stored elsewhere**.

```
e2fsck -b 98304 /dev/sdc1
```

Reboot and see if this worked.  If not try the next superblock on the list.  I've had to go the third or fourth one a couple of times.

```
e2fsck -b 163840 /dev/sdc1
```

Now try the command to validate the disk again.  See if you get the same messabout about bad superblocks.

```
fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdc1
```

Keep trying until you either run out of superblocks or it works.  If you run out, you likely have bigger issues and I hope you have good backups. You can try running FSCK at that point.

Comment: For me this did not work since my partition table got corrupted. I dealed with it with `testdisk`, my answer to a related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747574/459266.

Answer (score 10):

for me the problem was that the mount command contained options (umask, uid) which was not accepted (probably due to the device has ext4 file system)

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/ssd -o uid=pi,gid=pi
mount: /media/ssd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/ssd -o umask=000
mount: /media/ssd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

After removing the options, it worked

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/ssd
df -Th
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4      220G   61M  208G   1% /media/ssd
```

After mount the permissions or ownership can be set to able to have write permissions for non root users.

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/ssd
```

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to Ubuntu 20. Removing the option `nobarrier` from `/etc/fstab` on a XFS partition solved it.

Comment: Thanks! I would've never figured out. I just copy-pasted the line from an exFAT, but for an  ext4, so the user setting was not compatible.

Answer (score 5):

I had to install ntfs-3g as it was an NTFS formatted partition and Linux kernel versions before 5.15 didn't support ntfs out of the box. NTFS-3G is a FUSE filesystem (Filesystem in Userspace)

For me, the message appeared in dolphin. With installing ntfs-3g, dolphin can mount it properly.

Comment: Me too. For me it solved my issue and GParted guide me.

Answer (score 5):

My HD shows up in Gparted as `unallocated` but it isn't showing up in File (same thing in windows Disk management and File explorer)

I used [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recreate the partition table and **I was able to recover my HD and all the data without formatting it.**

1. In the terminal enter `testdisk`
2. Then choose create a log
3. Then select the HD and choose the partition type (most probably Intel)
4. Then select Analyse
5. If you only have 1 partition in your HD, then just mark the one that shows up as `Bootable partition` (with the   left-right arrow). Then press "Enter" to continue
6. If you had more, you should now do a "deeper search", otherwise choose `Write`

Unplug your HD and plug it again (this is what they mean, in this case, by "reboot")

Comment: For me it also worked with `testdisk` to solve `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1` as in my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747574/459266.

Comment: This worked for me! I followed step 1 to 4. For step 5, I just kept the default, and for step 6 I didn't bother with a deeper search despite having 3 partitions. Probably not the wisest, but I forgot what partitions/filesystem the drive had, so I opted to gamble it. Upon exiting testdisk, GNOME Disks showed individual partitions, I was able to mount the disk, and successfully recover all data.

Answer (score 3):

To get a usable volume out of a new disk, you have to carry the following steps:

1. Create a **partition table** on the disk, aka **disklabel**. there are two possible formats, `msdos` or `gpt`.
2. Create as many **partitions** as desired from the disk space. each partition is essentially defined by a **begin/end addresses** and **partition type**. The filesystem type is not definitely not a partition attribute, although some commands like `parted` may use it to set the partition type. Each partition will be considered as a block device on the system and accessible as a block file like `/dev/sdb1`.
3. Create a **filesystem** on the desired partition, which actually means organizing the partition raw space in a way suitable to store files/folders/links, etc., i.e. the file hierarchy. The filesystem attributes are stored in the superblock, which is generally one disk block at the very beginning in the partition space.

Given this short introduction, you'll notice that you still have to go through the third step. You may use for this `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1`.

Comment: From the question, it looks like the OP already did your steps 1 and 2. If you believe that there’s an error in the commands he used, say so. And [rudimeier’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/315063/80216#315070) (which is accepted and has nearly 200 votes) already covers your step 3.  Please don’t post duplicate answers. Do you have any *new* information or advice to contribute?

Comment: The question clearly states that the disk is new. So no need for warning twice in bold text that the disk will be wiped/content overwritten! If editing other's solution were possible I would suggested modifications.. I also wanted to add a summary of the full procedure of how to make a usable space out of a new disk. Nothing new. btw, would you please point me to some resources on why SE bot put this question on the top (no filtering)? Thanks.

Comment: If this question floated to the top of the list on the ‘‘front page’’, it’s probably because JingChen posted a new answer.   (You know; the one you commented on.)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but in case this helps anyone that stumbles across this.

I was attempting to connect and NFS mount but was failing and getting the same error as OP.

After installing the dependencies I was good to go:

`sudo apt install nfs-common`

Comment: This is unlikely to be an answer to *this* question, which has nothing to do with NFS. If you believe that you have valuable information to contribute, please [ask a new question](/questions/ask) that describes the problem that *you* encountered, and then post your answer there.  But first check [NFS does not work. mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65376/80216), which already has “install `nsf-common`” as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wasn't paying attention, and was trying to `mount /dev/sda /mnt` instead of `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`. Be careful out there!

Answer (score 2):

Unbelievable. I see this come up All the time. I can manually mount with the mount command no problem. When I try to `mount -a` I get the same bad fs type error. I looked at the `/etc/fstab` carefully and saw I spelled `default` **not** `defaults`. It is the spelling that gets me.

Answer (score 1):

```
# create mount dir
sudo mkdir /hdd6T

# new file system
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc

# mount drive
sudo mount /dev/sdc /hdd6T/

# change ownership to specified user
sudo chown your-user /hdd6T/
```

Comment: The question already says `mkdir` and `mount`, and the accepted answer says `mkfs.ext4`.  You’ve added `chown`, which has nothing to do with the question, so you aren’t really contributing any useful new information.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to mount a disk in linux mint. here is how is my secondary disk looks like
[image: linux mint disk management]

You just need to **create partition** from the menu and most done automatically, and mount options came automatically, disk is mounted under /media/
[image: extended partition]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error on boot and it was due to wrong filesystem entry on `/etc/fstab`.

The entry was

```
/dev/mapper/vgso-lvso /so xfs defaults 0 0
```

and it should be ext4 mounted

```
/dev/mapper/vgso-lvso /so ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: This is the gotcha, op also states the wrong file system type.

Answer (score 1):

If `dmesg` logs show something like

> [ 4990.686372] ntfs3: sda7: It is recommened to use chkdsk.
>
> [ 4990.734846] ntfs3: sda7: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!

It says that the NTFS partition has dirty flag set; Linux NTFS driver mounts R+W only if it isn't; RO mount works irrespective of dirtiness.

However, if you want R+W mount, this can be fixed by `ntfsfix -d`, if possible:

> ```
> -d, --clear-dirty
>     Clear the volume dirty flag if the volume can be fixed and mounted.  If the option is not present or the volume cannot be fixed, the  dirty volume flag is set to request a volume checking at next mount.
> ```

Running

```bash
$ ntfsfix -d /dev/sda7

Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda7 was processed successfully.
```

fixed the problem for me.

If this fails the next resort would be to use `chkdsk` on a Windows machine.

Refer [Why is NTFS has a dirty mark and why can't NTFS3 mount dirty NTFS partitions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/748468) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was some mysterious file causing this issue.

I had to clear the directory using the following command:

```
sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdf
```

**Warning**: this might delete files you have saved.  So you can run `ls` to make sure you don't lose important saved files and backup these files before execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to mount image file in any folder present in /home in ubuntu then try these Commands:

Generalized :

```
>>mkdir <name of your directory>
>>sudo mount -o ro <name of image file with extension> <name of your directory>/
```

Specified: name of your directory = system , name of image file with extension = system.img

```
>>mkdir system                                
>>sudo mount -o ro system.img system/
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case changing sata cable powering both drives and restart seems to fix the problem. however I was unable to mount them on the same old point so changing them fixed for me. then I manually remove the old mount points from mnt directory :)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. However, if you say you were "unable to mount them on the same old point" - what exactly do you mean by that? That you could no longer use the mount point you used previously to mount the drives, although you only exchanged the SATA cable?

Comment: yes. before it was sda1 and somehow I was unable to mount on it. even after removing that mount from the os itself. then I used different mount name and it worked. 

I mean to say I change the 15 points sata power cable and sata3 data cables.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone:
I was getting this issue for a different reason. I was trying to mount my entire `nvme0n1` drive, which was my dual boot system! And thus `mount` was complaining because I was trying to mount some Windows partitions (ntfs) onto my liveusb (ext4), causing errors visible in `dmesg`.

The solution was to check which section held my Linux install specifically via `sudo fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`, then mounting that one with `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt`.