# Malfunctioning brand new USB

Tags: linux, usb

Brand new 32 Gb usb, but when I plug it in, I can only see 5.5 kb. So, I cannot make any partition table on it.

I'm wondering if it can be fixed, or if it's a total loss.

I'm running Manjaro, with kernel 5.7.9-1

Output of `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M`:

```
dd: error writing '/dev/sda': No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
5632 bytes (5.6 kB, 5.5 KiB) copied, 1.65556 s, 3.4 kB/s
```

---

I tried some advice on this post [mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315063/mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock/543227#543227)
In my system, the usb is /dev/sda, and there are no partitions on it (no /dev/sda1)

Running `fsck -N /dev/sda` outputs

```
fsck from util-linux 2.35.2
[/usr/bin/fsck.ext2 (1) -- /dev/sda] fsck.ext2 /dev/sda
```

So I tried `fsck.ext2 -v /dev/sdc1` and got a bad suerblock message.

Running `mke2fs -n /dev/sa1` leads to

```
mke2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
/dev/sda contains `ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with no line terminators' data
Proceed anyway? (y,N)
```

If I say "y", I get `/dev/sda: Not enough space to build proposed filesystem while setting up superblock`

---

I also tried to run `gdisk /dev/sda`, where I can see "not present" for all partitions tables, and using the "verify disk" ("v" option) I get

```
Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last usable
sector is 18446744073709551593, but backup header is at
10 and disk size is 11 sectors.
```

If I try writing changes, I'll reach an error

```
Unable to save backup partition table! Perhaps the 'e' option on the expertsmenu will resolve this problem
The 'e' option on the experts menu will probably fix this problem
```

---

Any chance I can get it working?

Cheers, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M` where `sdX` is your **entire** flash drive (not just the first partition).

Comment: Edited to include the output you asked

Comment: `32 Gb usb` what?  ... it's like saying `I'll have a plate of hot`

Comment: If you used dd to write an ISO, you converted it to hybrid DVD/flash drive. You need to convert to standard partitioned drive. Only then can you create a partition. Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive
 You cannot run fsck on a drive, only ext4 formatted partition.

Comment: Please just check that `ls -l /dev/sda` shows it really is a device and not a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `dd` output your flash drive is completely broken. RMA it or dispose of it.

Comment: Thank you.... brand new :( Back to the store it is

Comment: QC for flash drives in my experience has always been horrible. I'm not surprised at all.