# How to mount this disk? (EBS)

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk, aws, aws-elb

I restored an EBS volume and attached it to a new EC2 instance. When I `lsblk` I can see it under the name `/dev/nvme1n1`.

More specifically the output of `lsblk` is:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   25M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
loop1         7:1    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop2         7:2    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1169
loop3         7:3    0 67.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21545
loop4         7:4    0 32.5M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13640
loop5         7:5    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2246
loop6         7:6    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
nvme0n1     259:0    0    8G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    8G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:2    0  100G  0 disk
```

As you can see `nvme1n1` has no partitions. As a result, when I try to mount it on a folder with:

```
sudo mkdir mount_point
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 mount_point/
```

I get

`mount: /home/ubuntu/mount_point: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

The volume has data inside:

```
/dev/nvme1n1: data
```

Using `sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1` to create a filesystem is not an option as Amazon states that:

> **Warning**
> Do not use this command if you're mounting a volume that already has data on it (for example, a volume that was created from a snapshot). Otherwise, you'll format the volume and delete the existing data.

Indeed I tried it with a second dummy ebs snapshot that I recovered and all I got is a dummy `lost+found` [linux folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix).

This EBS recovered snapshot has useful data inside, how can I mount it without destroying them?

---

```
# parted -l /dev/nvme1n1 print
Model: Amazon Elastic Block Store (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 8590MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8590MB  8589MB  primary  ext4         boot


Error: /dev/nvme1n1: unrecognised disk label
Model: Amazon Elastic Block Store (nvme)                                  
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

```
dmesg | grep nvme1n1
[   68.475368] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[   96.604971] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  254.674651] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[  256.438712] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

```
 sudo fsck /dev/nvme1n1
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/nvme1n1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Added the output of the command to the question!

Comment: Added at the bottom too.

Comment: Alright, before jumping into performing disk checks and stuff, I think you could try the following:  `mount -r -t ext4 /dev/nvme1n1 /some/mountpoint`  which will mount the disk `read-only` and in this case (since dmesg is showing ext4) it most probably is an ext4 file system.

Comment: `sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 ctf/ -t ext4` results to `mount: /home/ubuntu/ctf: special device /dev/nvme1n1p1 does not exist.`

Comment: @Dimitris  there is no `nvme1n1p1` . Here `p1` would refer to the first partition on the block device which you don't have as I mentioned in my previous comments which I deleted. You need to mount the whole disk since the partition (it seems ) has been created on the whole disk.

Comment: @ValentinBajrami Right. I did try to mount the whole disk as an ext4 with `sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 mount_point/ -t ext4` and it failed with the same message. Do I get something wrong?

Comment: @Dimitris. Did you try the `-r` flag? What does the dmesg show you then?

Comment: Same error with dmesg `[11877.345591] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem`

Comment: Why do you think it is `ext4` though? If you look above `Error: /dev/nvme1n1: unrecognised disk label`. `/dev/nvme0n1` which is the root is ext4. Is there a case this confused you?

Comment: `dmesg` is explicitly mentioning `EXT4-fs (nvme1n1): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem` . The `nvme0n1` has indeed the `boot` partition on ext4 but we don't have to deal with that.  I see there are some related posts like yours here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315063/mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock  Please have a look there but don't run `mkfs` or anything like this because this might cause data loss. Running `fsck` can help and won't harm.

Comment: I am aware of the post that you linked. I appended the output of `fsck` to the question.

Comment: "The volume has data inside: `/dev/nvme1n1: data`"... no, that just means `file` couldn't identify what the contents are. It could be garbage for all we know. It might be an encrypted volume. Nothing so far shows you have a valid filesystem there.

Comment: It cannot be garbage. It is just a volume restored for a healthly EBS snapshot made by AWS Backup. The encryption point is valid though, the disk is encrypted! But I am attaching the respective managed EBS KMS key to the volume provided by AWS

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the deleted partition.

See: [TestDisk Step By Step](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Answer (score -1):

i have been strugling with this myself
then it dawnd on me as information keeps comming in

disk util manage drives and media  and mount points use at you own risk
its a standard utility found in most linux distros

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421483)